# Get Legends and color code of a piechart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm using highcharts jquery file to create pie chart and trend chart. Right now i'm getting different color scheme for trend and pie chart . While plotting the trendchart, is there any way to get the colors used by the legends in the pie chart?

Reference http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-legend/gray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

```
Highcharts.getOptions().colors
```

is what i searched for. Thank You all.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the options, the `Highcharts Configuration Preview`, there's an object thats's passed,

```
plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            }
```

The property `showInLegend` is what you need I guess.

**EDIT:**

To get/set the colors used in the legends, click `View Visual Theme` on [this page](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-legend/gray), and you'll see the legend colors present in the `colors[]`,

```
colors: ["#DDDF0D", "#7798BF", "#55BF3B", "#DF5353", "#aaeeee", "#ff0066", "#eeaaee",
      "#55BF3B", "#DF5353", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee"]
```

Comment: That'll show the legends. I'm looking for a way to get the colors used by the legends.

Comment: i agree that we can set the colors using Highcharts.setOptions({

colors: ['#F64A16', '#0ECDFD',] });

Comment: What i really wanna know is the option to get the colors.

Comment: @NewBie `Highcharts.theme.colors`, this should return the array of colors

Answer (score 0):

Colors of the  legend is same with the colors of the series. And you can change the series color by setting the color field of the data option of the series object. Take a look at the following link to see the details.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.color

If you want to change the style of the legend text, you can use the itemStyle property of the legend object. But it looks like you can't set a different color for each series text in the legend itself, if you find a way to do it let me know I just couldn't figure it out.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemStyle